# Стоит ли изучать темы об указателях и ссылках?

Tags: указатели, ссылки, c++

Изучаю c++, очень сложно дается тема об указателях и ссылках. Можно ли пропустить ее и вернуться позже? Или без этих знаний дальнейшее изучение будет усложнено?

Comment: Вообще, лучший совет - найти обьяснение для себя, вариантов в нэте полно... Найти хоть в картинках и разберись... По Страуструппу точно нечего не поймешь....

Comment: Тоже кстати запутала тема поначалу. Разобрался сначала с указателями( на голом Си) потом уже понял что такое ссылки и с чем их едят.

Comment: вроде разобрался, очень сложно понимать теорию когда не понятно для чего конкретно на практике она будет использоваться

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если не будете знать ссылки и указатели, то можно уже не изучать C++

Comment: в НГУ (Новосибирск) на экзаменах тока про указатели и спрашивали... на 5-ку...

Comment: Узнаю почерк Альма Матер :)

Answer (score 3):

Это нереально. Надо быть избраннным

UPD

Так уж и быть, поделюсь своим воображением. Представь что вся доступная память - это такой старый, может школота уже и не помнит, настенный календарь, который раньше был на стене в каждом кабинете с передвигающимся красным указателем текущего дня - так вот, в плюсах, точно такая же модель, есть ячейки памяти, в них данные, по верх них бегает указатель на нужную дату.

Comment: Это не в плюсах такая модель памяти - а в компе так память и организована!

Comment: Неа, начало календаря и дно памяти находятся в противоположных концах.

Answer (score 1):

Как бы ни было тяжко в изучении данной темы, всё же придётся её осилить. Больше практики!

Answer (score 1):

Данная тема очень охорошо объясняется в книге Шилдта "c++ Базовый курс". Тут важно понять, что если перед указателем стоит "*" значит он на что-то указывает(на переменную, адресс который он содержит), если нет то, указатель это просто адрес в виде цифр.

Answer (score 0):

Это тоже самое что сказать "что-то циклы не понятны, пропущу, потом если встанет задача разберусь." Тема сама по себе не сложная, но возможно сложная для восприятия. Найди красивую картинку, где нарисованы объекты и указатели и все сразу поймется.